# How can I pass a variable from ant to a java file

Tags: java, ant, parameter-passing

I have some test cases in ant and each one of them pings an URL, I have a java class which is doing the work of pinging the URL and taking care of the things I need for my test case and I am compiling and running that java class from my ant build file.

The URL is different for all the test cases so I want to pass the URL from the ant file to the java class but I am having trouble doing that, does anyone have any suggestions how can I pass a variable from ant to an java class. Right now I am passing the URL in the java file itself for one test case but I don't want to create different java files for all the test cases just for a different URL each time.

This is my testcase 1 target which calls ping target:

```
<target name="01">
    <description>
    @testlogic.group type="category" values="mats"
    Incremental response data stress test, multi-thread model
    </description>
    <antcall target="pingOHSJava">
    <param name="out.log" value="tiapwt01.log"/>
    <param name="ohs.name" value="ohs1"/>
    <param name="url" value="/waiter/servlet/ServletStressMulti?mode=1"/>
    <param name="para1" value="1"/>  
    <param name="para2" value="10"/>
    <param name="para3" value="100"/>
    <param name="para4" value="10"/>
    </antcall>

    <fail message="test FAILED found.. failing">
        <condition>
            <resourcecontains resource="${tiapwt.base.dir}/common/output/tiapwt_content.txt" substring="FAILED"/>
        </condition>
    </fail> 
</target>
```

This is the ping target:

```
<target name="pingOHSJava">
    <property name="srcdir" location="${functional.base.dir}/tiapwt/common/java" />
    <path id="classpath.test">
        <pathelement location="/scratch/skaneria/Dwnld/junit-4.10.jar" />
    </path>
    <property name="lib.dir" value="../common/jars" />
    <taskdef resource="org/testlogic/toolkit/asserts/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="tlt-asserts-0.3.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <delete verbose="true">
            <fileset dir="${srcdir}" includes="**/*.class" />
        </delete>
    <property name="urlPing" value="http://${ADMIN_HOST}:${APACHE_PORT}${url}"/>
    <trycatch property="pingOutput">
    <try>
    <javac srcdir="${srcdir}" destdir="${srcdir}">
        <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
        </javac>
    <java classname="HttpURLConnectionExample" fork="true" failonerror="true">
    <classpath path="${srcdir}"/>

    </java>
    </try>
    <finally>
     <echo file="${twork.dir}/${out.log}" append="false">
URL: ${urlPing}
parameter 1 : mode=${para1}
parameter 2 : iterations=${para2}
parameter 3 : initial=${para3}
parameter 4 : increment=${para4}
------------------------------------------
${pingOutput}
       </echo>
    </finally>

    </trycatch>

    </target>
```

And this is a snippet from the java class which uses the URL:

```
private void sendGet() throws Exception {

        String url = "http://slc06mwj.us.oracle.com:7777/waiter/servlet/ServletStressMulti?mode=1&iterations=10&initial=100&increment=10000";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        try{
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        System.out.println("Response Message : " + con.getResponseMessage());
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error");
        }
```

Comment: Could you post your code here

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing command line arguments to Java via ant build script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237329/passing-command-line-arguments-to-java-via-ant-build-script)

Comment: ya I already went through that question and it's answers but it doesn't answer how to use the variable which has been passed from ant target in the java class.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using the answer from the above link it's working.